# Replacing electrical wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring

Can existing electrical wiring in a 35-year-old house be easily replaced to carry more amps by a Journeymen electrician? or will drywalls need to be opened for access?

Comment: First off, what are the circuits now? Everyone seems to assume that they are 15 amp and you'll be going to 20A, but I'd be surprised for a 35 year old house (so, 1984-5 era) to not have 20A outlet circuits already - which means you'd need to run more circuits and have fewer outlets per circuit, and possibly a new main panel to support more circuits.

Comment: *WHY* are you wanting to replace the wiring? Also, where on this planet are you located?

Comment: @Ecnerwal  I think you'd be surprised at how many 15 AMP, #14 AWG circuits are being put n new houses.

Comment: Opening drywall and skill of the electrician are somewhat unrelated aspects to the challenge at hand.

Comment: In general, no.  Unless the wire is in conduit (of a sufficient diameter) you can't simply pull out the old wire and pull in new stuff.

Comment: Does the capacity actually actually exist (not physical capacity) with the total current of all circuits v what rating the supplier fuse is?

Answer (score 8):

This is not an answer, but it's too long for a comment:

Consider the cost. A 4x8 sheet of Sheetrock ~$11. A contractor who has an electrical license is $75-150 per hour in my area. 
*If* you can find one who needs work. 
Some use small jobs as fillers but I find that a small job of updating a room can turn into a can of worms and take all day so it will usually be quoted T & M (Time and materials).

I find it easier to replace a panel than update old wiring, and the panel pays better, no crawling, + usually decent work area. (I don’t go under most houses - that is for the apprentices.)

Just trying to give you an idea of what to expect. Electricians are in short supply in the Pacific Northwest, and if the job is a PITA you might have trouble getting it done. Without opening the walls the job may cost 5×, but open the walls and the PITA factor drops and the price also along with the unknown factor.

You may find a hungry electrician out there but use caution & have a contract! Understand sometimes the cheapest quote up front may be the most expensive in the long run. Try to find someone with references, not just online stars.

And since this is a DIY site it may be a chance for you to learn and  save a few bucks. Going from a 15 to 20 amp circuit is quite simple: you are just installing #12 wiring. Take photos of each connection prior to taking it apart.  Mark wires with numbers if you think you will get things mixed up. After upgrading the wire size on the circuit snap in a 20 amp breaker and you have done it.

(In my state repair of a circuit - in this case just replacing individual components - doesn’t require a permit and can be done by a homeowner. Check your local regulations as from what I have read some states require an electrician for simple “device” outlet or switch  changes).

Answer (score 7):

If your house was wired with conduit then increasing wire size or adding new circuits would be relatively easy because new wire could be pulled in the existing conduit without cutting into the drywall. If your house was wired with NM cable, then it becomes more difficult. Drywall would have to be opened. If there's access to an attic and/or a basement, that would make it a bit easier.

Adding circuits, increasing loads, also depends on the ability of your main panel to handle the increase. A journeymen electrician would be able to do the job.

Comment: With NM cable, couldn't they just retire the old stuff in place and pull new? I thought that's what's usually done with knob/tube, and assume it could work for NM also.

Comment: You wouldn't normally retire NM cable  in a house only 35 years old, maybe if it was aluminum.  NB cable is installed without conduit, drilling studs and running it behind drywall. When  K&T  wiring is replaced, it's usually because of a renovation where the walls and you have access to the studs.

Comment: I agree+. some updates are possible with nmb wiring to go from 15 to 20 amp circuits but without opening walls it will be much more expensive, if you can find one to do it. For example I could easily run a circuit with multiple receptacles in most homes with the walls open in under an hour. With the walls / ceiling closed just a single outlet could take several hours maybe longer.  The nm in the walls will be stapled in several places and rarely can you use the original wire as a “pull” so you have to drill new holes and fish the wires it may be worth it on a tiled wall but Sheetrock doubt it.

Answer (score 6):

You have the right idea up-sizing the wire when you up-size the breaker.  Breakers protect wires.  But they don't protect *just* wires.  They also protect appliances. The appliances need breaker protection reasonably within their normal operating range.   If you wanted loads of capacity on a receptacle circuit and used 6 AWG wire/60A breaker, then a nominally-5A PC could burn at 55A and the breaker would let it burn.  Can't have that.

There is a variance in Code to allow common 15A receptacles on 20A circuits.  But that's it; that's the limit.

**What you really want is more circuits**.  Say you had three 1500W heaters and a PC to power.  You would use four 15/20A circuits for that.

A competent electrician can add circuits without disturbing drywall too much; this technique is called "fishing".

Comment: What's really cool is that a *really* sharp electrician can fish a 1/2" ENT (smurf tube) through the walls, which gives you room for more circuits than you could ever ask for XD

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  Notch the studs and cover with a nail plate?

Comment: @JACK I'd be more likely to bore the studs vs notching them

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  So bore at each stud and then fish smurf.

Comment: Fish smurf shall be the name of my band.

Comment: use the [right tool for the job](https://i.imgur.com/rriWupu.png)

Comment: Breakers do not protect appliances.  Appliances are supposed to protect themselves - that's part of UL/ETL/etc certification.

Comment: @J... Untrue. The UL/ETL etc. certification is dependent on a reasonable size breaker.  That is why appliance instructions will specifically tell you what breaker size to use. Build a dryer and write your instructions to call for any breaker ranging 30-70 amps. And see how exactly UL tells you "no" :)

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Well, I'll amend my prior statement to say that breakers protect wires *and* outlets.  Obviously you can't ask for a 14-30 outlet to be installed on a circuit protected by a 60A breaker because that outlet is not rated for the maximum current of the circuit.  A hardwire application would be different.  Just the same, you can't stick a 5-15 outlet on a circuit protected by a 40A breaker (which you're talking about) - not because of the attached appliances, but because the outlet itself is not rated for the maximum allowed current.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica In some sense I'll agree with you - the plug shape dictates a limit on the usable breaker, and that constrains the protection requirements of the attached appliances.  An 18awg appliance cord could not be used with a 5-15 plug if the anticipated maximum current exceeded 15-20A, certainly.   It obviously expects the breaker to also protect the run of cord from the plug to the appliance, so yes some parts of the appliance are implicitly protected by the breaker.  The outlet is still the first point of failure before we even get to the appliance, though.